# How to append file2 to file1 without changing their content, then output the result in file3

Tags: files, cat, file-copy

I have `file2` and `file1`. I want to append `file2` to file1 but without changing `file1`. I want to put the output in anew file `file3`.

If I used `cat file2 >> file1` this changes the content of `file1`.

Comment: Err... so `cat file1 file2 > file3` then?

Comment: If I want file2 content at the end, then `cat file2 file1` not `cat file1 file2` as you mentioned or am I wrong?

Comment: you are wrong, and please before asking a question or add comment test your consideration or other one suggestions. please let me know what did happen with `file2 >> file1` and what was your result of @steeldriver suggest?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a new file3 or file3 is empty.

```
cat file1 file2 > file3
```

If you want to append to file3.

```
cat file1 file2 >> file3
```

None of the above will modify file1 nor file2.

Comment: Thanks. Please correct the file names in the second command. You use file2 twice.